# Unit root connection with stationarity of time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root

Let's take the equation below :
$$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$

Now if :

(1) $\beta_1=1 \Rightarrow$ our time series contains unit root. It means that our time series $(y_t)$ is not stationary.

(2) $\beta_1<1 \Rightarrow$   our time series does not contain unit root, we can consider it as stationary.

I have two question about it :

(1) Is this true what I wrote in points (1) and (2) ? If yes, can you please share a mathematical proof of those facts ?

(2) I've never read what happens when $\beta_1>1$. I assume that we are even further from stationarity than in $\beta_1=1$ case. Am I right ?

Comment: In terms that are pedantic, but also pragmatic "stationary" ≠ "weakly stationary". The former includes both strong stationarity ($\beta_1 = 0$), and weak stationarity ($0< |\beta_1| <1$). Also note that $\beta_1$ can be negative, and that $-1$ is *also* a unit root.

Comment: The way your $y_t$ is specified, it will not be stationary even if $|\beta_1|<1$---solving for $y_t$ directly tells you there is a linear trend, $y_t = \beta_0 t + \sum_{h \geq 0} \beta_1^h \epsilon_{t-h}$.